# What is the proper way to do Ajax call with computed properties from VueX Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

How do I make ajax call with one of the call parameter being a computed State in VueX. For example, if I make this.$axios.get('someUrl/' + accID ), with accID being a computed property from VueX (via MapState). Sometimes id return 'undefined', which i  suspect is due to axios making get request before the id data is populated from store

I have tried using watch() on 'accID' in Vue component to wait until accID resolve but to no avail

//some partial code

```
 computed: {
    ...mapState(['user']),
  },

 async fetchData() {


        const [foodData, option] = await Promise.all([
          this.$axios({
            url: `food/${this.user.accID}`,
            method: 'get',
          }),
          this.$axios({
            url: 'options',
            method: 'get',
          })
        ])

  //foodData returns undefined because user.accID is undefined (sometimes)
```

Expecting

this.$axios({
url:'food/12345',
method: 'get'
})

Instead

this.$axios({
url:'food/undefined',
method: 'get'
})

Comment: Edited the url parameter slightly. I am pretty sure my original code has this.user.accID in it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `${user.accID}` to `${this.user.accID}` in `url`:

```
url: `food/${this.user.accID}`,
```